# Unity 2D C# hitbox with boxcollider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have some game objects on screen and added a polygon collider on them to detect normal collision with them. I would like to add a box collider on their head to detect headshot. How can i do this please? How can i state collision with box collider instead of polygon collider in C# please?

i tried this but only the polygon collider is getting detected

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) {
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "target")
    {
        score += 1000;
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
        gameObject.SetActive (true);
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
    else if(col is BoxCollider2D)
    {
        score += 2000;
        gameObject.SetActive (false);
        gameObject.SetActive (true);
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily check what type of collider was hit by just adding this in your Collision event :

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col is BoxCollider2D)
    {
        //When it hits the box
    }
    else if(col is PolygonCollider2D)
    {
        //When it hits the polygon
    }

}
```

In this case it will check if the collider is a BoxCollider2D or a PolygonCollider2D and in each `if` statement you can do what you need.

Comment: Instead of checking for the specific type of collider, you could use a tag or layer for all head-colliders instead. This would allow you to use other colliders in the same way, just by tagging them accordingly.

Comment: True, I would recommend that too. I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible for him so he doesn't need to add tags and all that @Lelefant

Comment: Thanks. Il'try it

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more BoxCollider2D Component on the item and position it on the head.
Remember to keep these in mind: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html